# pytest.mark.parametrize does not work as expected with pytest.lazy_fixture

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have a problem with the following code - the final result is not as expected:

**env.yaml**

```
config:
  requestenv: [test, uat]
  envinfo:
    test: [{imp: 111, clk: 111, "act": 111}, {imp: 222, clk: 222, act: 222}]
    uat: [{ imp: 333, clk: 333, act: 333 }, { imp: 444, clk: 444, act: 444 }]
```

**test_env.py**

```
import pytest
from utils import configutil

configpath = r".\monitor.request.config.yaml"

config = configutil.readyamlconfig(configpath)


requestenv = config["config"]["requestenv"]


@pytest.fixture(scope="function", params=requestenv)
def one(request):
    env = request.param
    return config["config"]["envinfo"][request.param]


@pytest.mark.parametrize("testdata", [pytest.lazy_fixture("one")])
def test_func01(testdata):
    print()
    print("*" * 10)
    print(testdata)
```

The test data always comes with an `env.yaml` config file, and depends on the test environment (`test` and `uat` in my case). I want to loop over every env and every item in that env, like below after running `pytest -s .\test_env.py`:

**[Expected]**

```
test_env.py::test_func01[test-{ imp: 111, clk: 111, act: 111 }]
test_env.py::test_func01[test-{ imp: 222, clk: 222, act: 222 }]
test_env.py::test_func01[saas-{ imp: 333, clk: 333, act: 333 }]
test_env.py::test_func01[saas-{ imp: 444, clk: 444, act: 444 }]
```

**[Actual]**

```
test_env.py::test_func01[test-[[{imp: 111, clk: 111, "act": 111}, {imp: 222, clk: 222, act: 222}]]]
test_env.py::test_func01[test-[{ imp: 333, clk: 333, act: 333 }, { imp: 444, clk: 444, act: 444 }]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see yet how to do this with `lazy-fixture`. The problem is that the number of tests in each of the test enviroments can vary, and I don't see how to reflect this in the fixture. If the number of tests is the same (as in your example), the following would work:

```py
@pytest.fixture(params=requestenv)
def envs(request):
    yield envinfo[request.param]

@pytest.fixture(params=range(len(envinfo["test"])))
def data(request, envs):
    yield envs[request.param]

def test_func01(data):
    print(data)
```

If the length of the data is variable, the only thing that comes to mind is using a hook to parametrize the function manually:

```py
def mydata():
    data = []
    ids = []  # not needed, just to make make the test name better readable
    for key in requestenv:
        data.extend([d for d in envinfo[key]])
        ids.extend([key + "-" + str(i) for i in range(len(envinfo[key]))])
    return data, ids

@pytest.hookimpl
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "testdata" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        data, ids = mydata()
        metafunc.parametrize("testdata", data, ids=ids)

def test_func02(testdata):
    print()
    print(testdata)
```

Both variants generate the expected output.

Probably I'm missing something here, and there is a nicer solution.

Comment: Sorry for the delay response, but with your first solution the env value should not hard code to "test" here: @pytest.fixture(params=range(len(envinfo["**test**"])))

Comment: That's why I wrote "if the number of tests ís the same" - in this case you can take the length of the tests in any environment. If this is not the case, the first solution will not work.

Comment: Thanks, then I will take the second solution.